# Encoding problem when fetching tags while editing CV

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, jobs, encoding

When editing the technologies I like on my CV profile on Careers 2.0 Stack Overflow. ( http://careers.stackoverflow.com/cv/edit/XXXX type of link), I noticed that there was some encoding problems while fetching the list of tags.

For instance if you look for [pi](/questions/tagged/pi), then it shows up as

```
Ï€ (pi) is a mathematical constant whose value is the ratio of any Euclidean plane circle's circumference to its diameter; this is the same value as the ratio of a circle's area to the square of its radius. It is approximately equal to 3.14159265 in decimal notation.
```

Instead of displaying "π" as it should and as it does everywhere else on StackExchange.

I checked the headers received from the AJAX request that fetch the list of tags and it does say `Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8`.

**Linked question:** https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252625/1524913 (same question that got closed but not migrated - *I don't know why*)

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the data coming from Stack Overflow - the "pi" character should be encoded as the HTML entity `&pi;`. I've submitted this as a tag edit to http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pi/info - I'm not a mod over there though so will have to wait for somebody to approve it!

Comment: @Alex you're lucky it [got approved](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4743269)! Better get yourself a diamond over there at SO. :)

Comment: Yeesh, some of those guys can be harsh... Anyway it turns out this doesn't fix the issue, because the problem is in the Excerpt (which is supposed to be plain text), not in the full "article" text (which happens to be the same text in this case, and is what I edited. I can't put HTML entities in the Excerpt though if it's supposed to be plain text).

Comment: @Alex get a diamond and hammer some courtesy into them! :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is now fixed. We weren't setting the correct encoding when retrieving tags from Stack Overflow, but now we are. So you can now enjoy a delicious slice of π in your Careers tag editor.